# Trying to turn my tex file into regression table - (Note: I am a beginner)

Tags: environments

I am saved some regression tables as a tex file. Then when I try to save it as a pdf, it ends up coming out damaged. Then when I try to typeset it, it says: "!LaTeX Error: Environment table undefined."

This is my tex file:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Logistic regression table\label{tab1}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
\hline\hline
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}\\
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{undereducated}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{undereducated}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{undereducated}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{undereducated}\\
\hline
undereducated&                     &                     &                     &                     \\
0.isco1d    &           0         &           0         &           0         &                     \\
            &         (.)         &         (.)         &         (.)         &                     \\
[1em]
Manager  &       4.117\sym{***}&       4.218\sym{***}&       4.181\sym{***}&                     \\
            &     (34.39)         &     (34.13)         &     (33.74)         &                     \\
[1em]
Professional  &       3.035\sym{***}&       2.408\sym{***}&       2.440\sym{***}&                     \\
            &     (27.27)         &     (20.49)         &     (20.74)         &                     \\
[1em]
Technician and associated professionals  &       5.513\sym{***}&       5.516\sym{***}&       5.608\sym{***}&                     \\
            &     (48.93)         &     (47.13)         &     (47.74)         &                     \\
[1em]
Clerical support workers  &      -2.061\sym{***}&      -2.061\sym{***}&      -2.018\sym{***}&                     \\
            &     (-4.47)         &     (-4.47)         &     (-4.38)         &                     \\
[1em]
Service and sales workers  &      -0.735\sym{***}&      -0.735\sym{***}&      -0.686\sym{***}&                     \\
            &     (-4.48)         &     (-4.48)         &     (-4.18)         &                     \\
[1em]
Agricultural, forestry workers  &       2.185\sym{***}&       2.185\sym{***}&       1.983\sym{***}&                     \\
            &     (19.53)         &     (19.53)         &     (17.65)         &                     \\
[1em]
Craft and related trades occupations  &      0.0605         &      0.0605         &      0.0367         &                     \\
            &      (0.46)         &      (0.46)         &      (0.28)         &                     \\
[1em]
Plant and machine operators  &      -0.463\sym{**} &      -0.463\sym{**} &      -0.438\sym{**} &                     \\
            &     (-2.87)         &     (-2.87)         &     (-2.72)         &                     \\
[1em]
Elementary Occupations  &           0         &           0         &           0         &                     \\
            &         (.)         &         (.)         &         (.)         &                     \\
[1em]
female\_mgr  &                     &      -0.355\sym{**} &      -0.269\sym{*}  &                     \\
            &                     &     (-3.19)         &     (-2.39)         &                     \\
[1em]
female\_prof &                     &       0.954\sym{***}&       0.990\sym{***}&                     \\
            &                     &     (18.55)         &     (19.13)         &                     \\
[1em]
female\_tech &                     &    -0.00610         &    0.000279         &                     \\
            &                     &     (-0.11)         &      (0.00)         &                     \\
[1em]
age         &                     &                     &      0.0270\sym{***}&      0.0309\sym{***}\\
            &                     &                     &     (22.69)         &      (9.41)         \\
[1em]
regions     &                     &                     &     -0.0340\sym{***}&     -0.0386\sym{***}\\
            &                     &                     &     (-5.41)         &     (-3.44)         \\
[1em]
Generic Programs  &                     &                     &                     &           0         \\
            &                     &                     &                     &         (.)         \\
[1em]
Education &                     &                     &                     &       1.208\sym{***}\\
            &                     &                     &                     &      (9.25)         \\
[1em]
Arts & Humanities &                     &                     &                     &      -0.219         \\
            &                     &                     &                     &     (-1.50)         \\
[1em]
Social sciences, journalism and information &                     &                     &                     &      0.0161         \\
            &                     &                     &                     &      (0.14)         \\
[1em]
Business, administration and law &                     &                     &                     &      -0.404\sym{***}\\
            &                     &                     &                     &     (-3.70)         \\
[1em]
Natural sciences, mathematics and statistics &                     &                     &                     &      -0.479\sym{***}\\
            &                     &                     &                     &     (-3.36)         \\
[1em]
ICT &                     &                     &                     &      -0.119         \\
            &                     &                     &                     &     (-0.70)         \\
[1em]
Engineering, manufacturing and construction &                     &                     &                     &      -0.335\sym{***}\\
            &                     &                     &                     &     (-3.66)         \\
[1em]
Agriculture, forestry, fishery and veterinary sciences &                     &                     &                     &       0.299\sym{*}  \\
            &                     &                     &                     &      (2.09)         \\
[1em]
Health and welfare &                     &                     &                     &       2.608\sym{***}\\
            &                     &                     &                     &     (28.88)         \\
[1em]
Services&                     &                     &                     &      0.0161         \\
            &                     &                     &                     &      (0.12)         \\
[1em]
Unknown&                     &                     &                     &      -0.929         \\
            &                     &                     &                     &     (-1.58)         \\
[1em]
\_cons      &      -4.662\sym{***}&      -4.662\sym{***}&      -5.724\sym{***}&      -3.876\sym{***}\\
            &    (-42.78)         &    (-42.78)         &    (-46.01)         &    (-32.74)         \\
\hline
\(N\)       &      101394         &      101394         &      101394         &       36005         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I am really new to this so would appreciate any help I can get. If I am breaking any guidelines on asking questions, apologies and let me know how I can fix it. Many thanks in advance!

Best,
M. Qamar

Comment: Is that your *entire* tex file?  Because it should begin `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}` and end `\end{document}`.

Comment: Yes that is. This was the output from some regressions I ran on Stata. Should I just insert those lines at the beginning and end of the code?

Comment: My guess would be that Stata gave you that output so that you could `\input` it into an existing TeX file.  That way, you could have several table files in one pdf output.

Answer (score 1):

In the following example, I have added the missing documentclass as well as `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. I've loaded the `geometry` package in oder to have smaller margins and the `longtable` package to allow page breaks within the table. In order to make the table narrower (as it exceeds the textwidth), I have used a fixed width `p` type column that allows for automated linebreaks in the first column. In order to left align the contents of the first column, I have used the  `array` package and `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}


\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}

\begin{longtable}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm}*{4}{c}}
\caption{Logistic regression table\label{tab1}}\\
\hline\hline
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}\\
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{undereducated}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{undereducated}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{undereducated}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{undereducated}\\
\hline \endhead
undereducated&                     &                     &                     &                     \\
0.isco1d    &           0         &           0         &           0         &                     \\
            &         (.)         &         (.)         &         (.)         &                     \\
[1em]
Manager  &       4.117\sym{***}&       4.218\sym{***}&       4.181\sym{***}&                     \\
            &     (34.39)         &     (34.13)         &     (33.74)         &                     \\
[1em]
Professional  &       3.035\sym{***}&       2.408\sym{***}&       2.440\sym{***}&                     \\
            &     (27.27)         &     (20.49)         &     (20.74)         &                     \\
[1em]
Technician and associated professionals  &       5.513\sym{***}&       5.516\sym{***}&       5.608\sym{***}&                     \\
            &     (48.93)         &     (47.13)         &     (47.74)         &                     \\
[1em]
Clerical support workers  &      -2.061\sym{***}&      -2.061\sym{***}&      -2.018\sym{***}&                     \\
            &     (-4.47)         &     (-4.47)         &     (-4.38)         &                     \\
[1em]
Service and sales workers  &      -0.735\sym{***}&      -0.735\sym{***}&      -0.686\sym{***}&                     \\
            &     (-4.48)         &     (-4.48)         &     (-4.18)         &                     \\
[1em]
Agricultural, forestry workers  &       2.185\sym{***}&       2.185\sym{***}&       1.983\sym{***}&                     \\
            &     (19.53)         &     (19.53)         &     (17.65)         &                     \\
[1em]
Craft and related trades occupations  &      0.0605         &      0.0605         &      0.0367         &                     \\
            &      (0.46)         &      (0.46)         &      (0.28)         &                     \\
[1em]
Plant and machine operators  &      -0.463\sym{**} &      -0.463\sym{**} &      -0.438\sym{**} &                     \\
            &     (-2.87)         &     (-2.87)         &     (-2.72)         &                     \\
[1em]
Elementary Occupations  &           0         &           0         &           0         &                     \\
            &         (.)         &         (.)         &         (.)         &                     \\
[1em]
female\_mgr  &                     &      -0.355\sym{**} &      -0.269\sym{*}  &                     \\
            &                     &     (-3.19)         &     (-2.39)         &                     \\
[1em]
female\_prof &                     &       0.954\sym{***}&       0.990\sym{***}&                     \\
            &                     &     (18.55)         &     (19.13)         &                     \\
[1em]
female\_tech &                     &    -0.00610         &    0.000279         &                     \\
            &                     &     (-0.11)         &      (0.00)         &                     \\
[1em]
age         &                     &                     &      0.0270\sym{***}&      0.0309\sym{***}\\
            &                     &                     &     (22.69)         &      (9.41)         \\
[1em]
regions     &                     &                     &     -0.0340\sym{***}&     -0.0386\sym{***}\\
            &                     &                     &     (-5.41)         &     (-3.44)         \\
[1em]
Generic Programs  &                     &                     &                     &           0         \\
            &                     &                     &                     &         (.)         \\
[1em]
Education &                     &                     &                     &       1.208\sym{***}\\
            &                     &                     &                     &      (9.25)         \\
[1em]
Arts \& Humanities &               &                          &                     &      -0.219         \\
            &                     &                     &                     &     (-1.50)         \\
[1em]
Social sciences, journalism and information &                     &                     &                     &      0.0161         \\
            &                     &                     &                     &      (0.14)         \\
[1em]
Business, administration and law &                     &                     &                     &      -0.404\sym{***}\\
            &                     &                     &                     &     (-3.70)         \\
[1em]
Natural sciences, mathematics and statistics &                     &                     &                     &      -0.479\sym{***}\\
            &                     &                     &                     &     (-3.36)         \\
[1em]
ICT &                     &                     &                     &      -0.119         \\
            &                     &                     &                     &     (-0.70)         \\
[1em]
Engineering, manufacturing and construction &                     &                     &                     &      -0.335\sym{***}\\
            &                     &                     &                     &     (-3.66)         \\
[1em]
Agriculture, forestry, fishery and veterinary sciences &                     &                     &                     &       0.299\sym{*}  \\
            &                     &                     &                     &      (2.09)         \\
[1em]
Health and welfare &                     &                     &                     &       2.608\sym{***}\\
            &                     &                     &                     &     (28.88)         \\
[1em]
Services&                     &                     &                     &      0.0161         \\
            &                     &                     &                     &      (0.12)         \\
[1em]
Unknown&                     &                     &                     &      -0.929         \\
            &                     &                     &                     &     (-1.58)         \\
[1em]
\_cons      &      -4.662\sym{***}&      -4.662\sym{***}&      -5.724\sym{***}&      -3.876\sym{***}\\
            &    (-42.78)         &    (-42.78)         &    (-46.01)         &    (-32.74)         \\
\hline
\(N\)       &      101394         &      101394         &      101394         &       36005         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks leandriis! I used the code and it worked!